# How i can connect http client

Tags: xamarin

I have two projects 
one is api project(web service) 
one is xamarin project that consume api project.Xamarin 
project can consume standart api like this (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/) 
but can't consume my project i get an error "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request"

Here is my Http client connection code:

```
#HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        return client;
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution to debugging Your REST Service From Your Emulator/Device Using **SharpProxy**
https://www.barelycompetent.co.za/debugging-your-rest-service-from-your-emulator-device-using-sharpproxy/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in an async method, you should have api response in response_string once it runs.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/") });
var response_string = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: @Erkan, problem is in your api, are you sure its working correctly and accessible by client app. Try using coinmarketcap api instead as I have in code above, if that works means you should fix your api.

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me if it works :)

private string Url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/";

```
    public async Task<List<Todo>> GetTodos()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);

        var todoes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todo>>(json);

        return todoes;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is httpClient connect this ("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/") but on localhost can't connect like this (http://localhost/ServiceHub/api/akademi/) .Is there any properties that i don't know maybe i should change settings or something?

Comment: Try this : https://www.barelycompetent.co.za/debugging-your-rest-service-from-your-emulator-device-using-sharpproxy/